# Var_dump output

Tags: php, dump, var

I've converted this array from stdclass object.

I'm using var_dump to print the output of an array which is something like this:

```
array (size=1)
  'fruits' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => 
        object(stdClass)[2]
            public 'name' => string 'apple' (length=5)
            public 'origin' => string 'kashmir' (length=7)
            public 'number' => int 50
      1 => 
        object(stdClass)[1]
            public 'name' => string 'orange' (length=6)
            public 'origin' => string 'nevada' (length=6)
            public 'number' => int 20
```

I know var_dump also gives the datatype and length. However, I want the output to be something like this:

```
1.{
   'name':'apple',
   'origin':'kashmir',
   'number':50
   },
2.{
  'name':'orange',
  'origin':'nevada',
  'number':20
  }
```

Can anybody please help me?

Comment: Which programming language are you using? PHP?

Comment: yes, I'm using php and the Zend framework

Answer (score 0):

try the json_encode($array) function   http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: if I use json_encode(), it'll give a json string like

{"fruits":[{"name":"apple","origin":"kashmir","number":50},{"name":"orange","origin":"nevada","number":20}]}

However, I want the output the to be formatted as above.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the same output as your example you will probably need to implement a serializer.
There are also this functions that you could use:
[print_r](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php), [serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php)

> EDIT

Try this script:

```
foreach($array['fruits'] as $key=>$fruit) {
   echo ($key+1) . ".{\n";
   echo "\t'name':'$fruit->name',\n";
   echo "\t'number':'$fruit->number'\n";
   echo "},\n";
}
```

Note that I have not tested this script.

Comment: The serialize() returns a string just like a json string

Comment: Thank you so much. That does work with a little bit of editing.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<pre>"; print_r($myarray); echo "</pre>";
```

that gives something like you asked.

Comment: Thank you, that does make it much more readable. I get the output like this: Array
(
    [fruits] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [name] => apple
                    [origin] => kashmir
                    [number] => 50
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [name] => orange
                    [origin] => nevada
                    [number] => 20
                )   Is there anyway I could remove the word "array" and "stdClass Object"?